# More silverfish appearing? How do I stop this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While I was playing Minecraft hunger games, a silverfish attacked me. I started to fight it, but more kept on spawning. Is this a bug? How can I stop it? I already tried killing the silverfish but more spawn after it.

Comment: @reviewing-person-who-didnt-accept-my-edit Why? I clarified it quite a bit...

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach [You can see who rejected, and why](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/73571).  Apparently, you got a "Too Minor" AND a "Radical change".

Comment: Technically it is a bug, but not the software kind: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverfish

Comment: Are they bugs? I thought they were fish. :D

Comment: @Robotnik Stizzle's question wasn't whether or not Silverfish are supposed to kill, it was whether or not more are supposed to spawn. I discussed this with him at my [General Communication chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12970/general-communication).

Comment: @Frank Is there any way I can explain to the reviewers why my edit was more important? Should I reverse Robotnik's edit, or retry my edit?

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach The best you can do is point them at the conversation you've had, and that's it.  Short of that, it's up to the asker to reword it.

Comment: @Frank Is Stizzle able to reword his own question without a peer review on his edit?

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach It's his own question; he can edit it as much as he likes.

Comment: @Frank Doesn't it become a "community wiki" question if he edits it enough, or is that just for answers?

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach Nope, it'll happen to his question, too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No, this is not a bug. It is an intentional feature.** (though I've never seen it in Hunger Games before)

In Minecraft, there are "bug blocks" accessible in the creative inventory. They look exactly like stone bricks (or a variation of), stone, or cobblestone. These blocks are called ID's similar to "Stone Brick Monster Egg."

Silverfish have a special property - when they get hit, they summon more. They can only summon more from these bug blocks, destroying the block in the process*. If left alone, a silverfish will disappear into a non-bug stone, cobble or stone brick block and turn it into a bug block.

Whenever devious map makers want to cause chaos, they often spawn in a silverfish and surround it with bug blocks. Apparently the Hunger Games map had bug blocks, and you attacking the silverfish summoned more.

*Bug blocks also summon silverfish when broken by the player.

You can **prevent a horde of silverfish** by:

- **One hitting the silverfish**. Silverfish which are one-hitted (killed in one strike with a weapon) don't summon more, even if there are bug blocks around.
- **Not digging bug blocks**. When you try to dig a bug block, it will dig sort of slow compared to a pickaxe, but quite quickly compared to the fist. It is a unique digging speed, meaning it can't be reproduced with a pickaxe - so experienced players can tell if they are digging a bug block.
- **Running**. Though it might be obvious, as with most any other slower-than-player mob your best chance of survival is running.

Comment: As of 1.13, bug blocks now break instantly, so one can no longer "not dig" them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really easy way to get rid of a swarm of silverfish in Creative Mode: dig down until you fall out of the world and, when you respawn, all the silverfish will be gone!